# CallerMemberName to be used with INotifyPropertyChange for VB?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to implement the CallerMemberName to be used with raising properties. I'm trying to do this in vb but can't find this interface in the system.runtime.compilerservices. First question is is this even possible for vb yet or is it just for c#? Thanks for help.

```
Public Sub RaisePropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName> Optional propertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`CallerMemberName` really is `CallerMemberNameAttribute` in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`. It's definitely there as long as you're using .Net 4.5. And it works in VB.Net just fine, for me at least.

Comment: .net 4.5 or later

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the Target framework is set to .NET 4.5